# How can we find the balance of credits in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way, we can figure out how many remaining credits we have in snowflake?

Thanks.

Comment: The amount of credits used are shown from the UI - Accounts - Usage. I think if the total credits are known then the amount left can be deduced.

Answer (score 4):

The amount of credits used are shown from the UI - Accounts - Usage. If the total credits are known then the amount left can be deduced.

Also, you may get details of daily balance from here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/organization-usage/remaining_balance_daily.html

```
select * from ORGANIZATION_USAGE.REMAINING_BALANCE_DAILY
```

Comment: ORGANIZATION_USAGE.REMAINING_BALANCE_DAILY does not show anything for accountadmins btw.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to find credit consumption is classic Web UI and New Web Interface:

[Viewing Account-level Credit and Storage Usage in the Web Interface](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-monitoring-usage.html)

The key point are privileges required to see this kind of data:

> Only account administrators (i.e. users with the ACCOUNTADMIN role) or a role with the global MONITOR USAGE privilege can access the billing and usage information in the classic web interface.
>
> Only account administrators can access the billing and usage information in the new web interface.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done in SQL. In fact, this is what happens behind the scenes when you use the web interface. Provided that you have sufficient privileges (ie, users users with the `ACCOUNTADMIN` role or a role with the global `MONITOR USAGE` privilege), you can query the `warehouse_metering_history` Account Usage view. For example, credits used by each warehouse in your account (month-to-date):

```sql
USE "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE";

SELECT warehouse_name,
       SUM(credits_used) AS total_credits_used
FROM   warehouse_metering_history
WHERE  start_time >= Date_trunc(month, current_date)
GROUP  BY warehouse_name
ORDER  BY total_credits_used;
```

Or, credits used over time by each warehouse in your account (month-to-date):

```sql
SELECT start_time :: DATE AS usage_date,
       warehouse_name,
       SUM(credits_used)  AS total_credits_used
FROM   warehouse_metering_history
WHERE  start_time >= Date_trunc(month, current_date)
GROUP  BY usage_date,warehouse_name
ORDER  BY warehouse_name, usage_date;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#account-usage-views